# How to fallback on second query if the first query yields no result?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a Select-Statement A. If it yields no result, I want the result from Select B to be used. Select B is a 'fallback' for Select A if you will.

Select A:

```
SELECT b FROM table_with_name WHERE a = 1
```

SELECT B:

```
SELECT b FROM other_table_with_name WHERE a = '-8'
```

Usually I would use 'OR', but given the statements rely on completely different TABLES this doesn't seem possible.  How do I do that?

**Example:**

table_with_name

```
+---+-----+
| a | b   |
+---+-----+
| 1 | abc |
+---+-----+
| 2 | def |
+---+-----+
| 3 | ghi |
+---+-----+
```

other_table_with_name

```
+----+-----+
| a  | b   |
+----+-----+
| -8 | xyz |
+----+-----+
| 7  | mno |
+----+-----+
| 11 | tuv |
+----+-----+
```

**Wanted Results**

```
+-----+
| abc |
+-----+
```

If that entry were to be deleted, this (fallback) result is wanted:

```
+-----+
| xyz |
+-----+
```

Comment: Depending on your queries and your data you can use union or join to get the expected output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do a `UNION ALL`. If the first `SELECT` returns a non-empty result, you are done. Otherwise return the second `SELECT`'s result:

```
SELECT a FROM table_with_name WHERE a = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT b FROM other_table_with_name
WHERE b = 'xyz'
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT a FROM table_with_name WHERE a = 1)
```

Answer (score -1):

⚠ This solution will raise an error if there is more than one result (*subquery returned more that 1 row*).

Using a CASE this can be done:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN EXISTS (SELECT b FROM table_with_name WHERE a = 1)
            THEN (SELECT b FROM table_with_name WHERE a = 1)
            ELSE (SELECT b FROM other_table_with_name WHERE a = '-8')
    END AS your_result
```

Should a result be found for the first statement, it will be used. If not, the query in the ELSE part will be executed.